# How to extract running Apache configuration from core dump?

Tags: apache-httpd, memory, debugging, core-dump

Apache is loading the configuration from files into its memory. If the config files are changing the Apache process won't activate it until a reload/restart happens.

Now I have to debug the current running Apache configuration (particularly the Vhost config). For now I have dumped the Apaches memory with gcore. So how would I have to proceed to extract the relevant parts of the memory dump to get to the Vhost config? (I assume the config does not get stored in plain text in Apaches memory and there is some magic needed to decode the memory).

I think it might be really complex to debug it this way.

Comment: guys, when (before) voting to close, please add a comment explaining why. I can't see what's unclear about this question.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Strange, I also don't get the point of closing the question. It is still unclear how to get configuration from a running Apache process (if it is possible at all).

Comment: related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943
https://superuser.com/questions/922869
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129026
https://serverfault.com/questions/425894
https://serverfault.com/questions/696164
https://serverfault.com/questions/500329
https://serverfault.com/questions/489018
https://serverfault.com/questions/42539

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/invoking.html

Answer (score 2):

> I think it might be really complex to debug it this way.

Me too.  There's no reason to believe that Apache simply reads the configuration into memory and consults it now and again -- more likely, many of the options integrally affect how apache *configures itself* at start-up.

So you would have to understand the structure of the apache source code and then start trying to figure out where the various bits and pieces would end up in a core dump.

If someone doesn't have a tool for this already (I'm guessing they don't) then I would try to find some other solution to your problem.

Comment: Okay, this really seems to be a complex thing. I already found some plain-text configuration in the core dump but I do not know why this individual Vhost was there and how Apache acts with this.